# I think I made a mistake installing an Ubuntu server, how do I fix this?

Tags: server, 20.04

The laptop I'm using is an old HP Stream (I can't remember the exact model number), and I made a noob mistake and forgot to check for an Ethernet port.  Apparently this laptop doesn't have one and I'm kicking myself for making that kind of mistake.

The server I'm trying to install is Ubuntu 20.04, and I didn't select the option to use third-party things during installation.  So now I have a server that can't install new packages since it doesn't have a connection to the internet.

Should I just figure out how to uninstall it and start over, or am I missing a very obvious answer like how I missed the fact this laptop doesn't have a freakin' Ethernet port?

Comment: Use a desktop version of Ubuntu. It will be able to use the WiFi. The regular Ubuntu may be too heavy for HP Stream. Use Xubuntu instead

Comment: You don't need to *uninstall* an OS if that's what you decide to do... You just install an OS and it'll overwrite what was there beforehand. Ubuntu Server defaults to an older GA kernel stack; so your 20.04 will give you a 2020-April kernel stack, some ISOs allow you to change this during install, otherwise you can download packages on another box; write to USB-thumb-drive & walk it to your machine, plug in and install from media (like we did before internet everywhere; *sneaker net* I've heard it being called)  Your choice.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I install software or packages without Internet (offline)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/974/how-can-i-install-software-or-packages-without-internet-offline)

Comment: USB-to-Ethernet adapter dongles are cheap and plentiful.